# Scala type casting of function result

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and can't get my head around this type related problem.

Trying to knock up a function that would convert a list of tuples of key-value (key might be non-unique) to a list of tuples of aggregated values belonging to specific keys selected using extra list of 'columns'. The out needs to have signature of Array[Array[Any]]:

Example:

Input:

```
[("k1", 10), ("k2", 15), ("k1", 18), ("k3", 23), ("k1", 13), ("k2", 1)]
```

columns:

```
COLUMNS = ["k1", "k2"]
```

output:

```
[[10, 18, 13], [15, 1]]
```

My attempt looks like:

```
val COLUMNS = Array("k1", "k2")

def convert(result: Array[Tuple2[String, Any]]): Array[Array[Any]] = { 
    val grouped = result.groupBy(cell => cell._1)
    val columns = grouped.mapValues(cell => cell.map(column => column._2))

    val tuples = COLUMNS.map(col => columns.getOrElse(col, Array()))
    return tuples
}
```

I am getting following error though:

```
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[Array[_]]
 required: Array[Array[Any]]
         return tuples
```

Can anyone help please? Note I need the Array[Array[Any]] type in the end...
Thanks.

Comment: Your described output type is `Array[Array[Any]]` whilst your example output is `[(Int, Int, Int), (Int, Int)]` which could be `Array[Any]` but not `Array[Array[Any]]` which demands an extra array.  Is your desired output more like this?: `[[10, 18, 13], [15, 1]]`

Comment: @Rajit: yes, fixed in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just specify `Any` explicitly for empty array, because it has `Nothing` type by default here (I also removed unnecessary return and unconventional caps-lock, simplified lambdas) :

```
val Columns = Array("k1", "k2")

def convert(result: Array[(String, Any)]): Array[Array[Any]] = { 
      val grouped = result.groupBy(_._1)
      val columns = grouped.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
      Columns.map(columns.getOrElse(_, Array[Any]()))
}

scala> convert(Array(("k1", 10), ("k2", 15), ("k1", 18), ("k3", 23), ("k1", 13), ("k2", 1)))
res2: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(10, 18, 13), Array(15, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` is the key to this kind of work:

```
val kvs = Array(("k1", 10), ("k2", 15), ("k1", 18), ("k3", 23), ("k1", 13), ("k2", 1))

scala> Array("k1", "k2") map kvs.groupBy(_._1) map (_ map (_._2))
res16: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(10, 18, 13), Array(15, 1))
```

Note that we are taking advantage of the fact that a `Map` can be used as a *function* from key to value.  The result of the `groupBy` in this case is a `Map` from key to the tuples containing it; we `map` that `Map` (using it as a function) over the keys of interest to get their tuples, and then extract the values from them.

If some of the keys you are after might not be present in the input at all, you can use `withDefaultValue` to say that an empty array should be returned in that case:

```
scala> Array("k1", "k2", "k9") map (kvs.groupBy(_._1) withDefaultValue Array()) map (_ map (_._2))
res17: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(10, 18, 13), Array(15, 1), Array())
```

The resulting type will be as specific as it can be, which is probably what you want.  But of course if you want to widen it you can do so with type ascription, or simply by declaring with the wider type the variable receiving the result.

Comment: Also, be careful with `mapValues` -- it returns a view.  See #36 on this page: https://nicholassterling.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/scala-snippets/